# How to escape brackets in string (panda)?

Tags: pandas

I have columns strings including brackets. How can I escape it in panda?

```
df['Request Type [list]'] = df['Request Type [list]'].replace(['Technical Issues and Bugs'],'Unassigned')
```

Getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2895, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1675, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1683, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Request Type [list]'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/python/remove-columns/main.py", line 60, in <module>
    df['Request Type [list]'] = df['Request Type [list]'].replace(['Technical Issues and Bugs'],'Unassigned')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2906, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Request Type [list]'
```

Comment: Check `print (df.columns.tolist())`

Comment: escape is not necessary

Comment: I think we dont understand each other. I have column header "Request Type [List]" and panda does not like the brackets in the column name.